# Issue with installation of Mendeley plugin for Microsoft Word 2019

Tags: microsoft-word, plugins, mendeley

I am trying to install Mendeley plugin for Microsoft Word 2019 v16.01 via standart menu Tools in Mendeley Desktop 1.19.3 and it just hangs and no respond.
Then I tried to install it manally by copying .dotm file into Autostart folder of MS Word. Mendeley recognizes it as installed but if you try to go to References tab in Word it just hangs nad no respond. 
Win 10. MS Office 2019 x86.

Comment: I get the same issue with Word 2016 in Windows 10

Comment: I tried and I have this issue also for Word 2016 in Win 10.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with Mendeley v1.19.4 and Word 2016 Professional Plus. Any progress on a solution?